# Mac OS X terminal set text no wrap?

Tags: macos

easier to grep / diff results. 
ideally with a horizontal scroll bar...

did not find settings in preferences...

Answer (score 4):

A much better option that I just realized is to use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which comes with OS X.

Type `screen` in your terminal window, and then type `Ctrl-A` followed by `:` to enter command mode. You can then type the command `width -w 300` (replacing any number with 300 suitable for your purposes). The width command sets the terminal width of the virtual terminal in `screen`, (in my example, 300 characters) with the `-w` option, telling screen to not attempt to resize the actual terminal window.

The diff that you are viewing will now extend past your OS X Terminal window and you can use the left and right arrow keys to scroll left and right.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is pipe the output to "less -S" and use the cursor keys to move left/right.

Answer (score 2):

Piping the output into less -S won't quite do what you are looking for, it will chop the lines to your terminal width and you will loose display of some data. However, I think it's the closest you'll get without resorting to a GUI app. If you use a GUI app you can open your file in (e.g. bbedit) and turn line wrapping off. Bbedit also has good command line tools, bbedit and bbdiff. You can pipe into bbedit, it will open a new window. You can use Bbdiff as you diff tool and see the results graphically.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to diff results, use the FileMerge app which is installed with the OS X developer tools. It also has a command line interface `opendiff file1 file2`

[image]